# Line break in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a simple batch file (**forbat.bat**), with the following content:

```
FOR /F "tokens=4 delims=," %%G IN ("deposit,$4500,123.4,12-AUG-09") DO @echo Date paid %%G
```

When I run this batch file, I can get the result.

Now, I want to break the lines into a few lines, to make them easier to read. This is what I did:

```
FOR /F "tokens=4 delims=," %%G IN ("deposit,$4500,123.4,12-AUG-09") 
 DO 
 @echo Date paid %%G
```

This time, I got a "The syntax of the command is incorrect" error.

It seems that I must have missed some semicolons and slashes when introducing the line breaks. How to make the above code work in windows batch file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct syntax, that works on my Windows XP machine:

```
FOR /F "tokens=4 delims=," %%G IN ("deposit,$4500,123.4,12-AUG-09") DO (  
@echo Date paid %%G 
@echo hiforbat )
```

This is the output:

```
Date paid 12-AUG-09
hi
```

Answer (score 8):

As Dennis said, you can use the caret, *but* you mustn't have spaces at the start of the following lines:

```
FOR /F "tokens=4 delims=," %%G IN ("deposit,$4500,123.4,12-AUG-09") ^ 
DO ^ 
echo Date paid %%G
```

Otherwise it doesn't work. However, if you are willing to leave the `DO` in the original line, you can use parentheses to delimit a block

```
FOR /F "tokens=4 delims=," %%G IN ("deposit,$4500,123.4,12-AUG-09") DO (
   @echo Date paid %%G
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a carat "`^`" for a line continuation character at the end of each line where commands are split.

```
FOR /F "tokens=4 delims=," %%G IN ("deposit,$4500,123.4,12-AUG-09") ^
DO ^
echo Date paid %%G
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work: I got a `DO ^` thing printed out and that was it.

Comment: It doesn't like any indentation or the @ sign apparently.